# How to extract .bz2 using Ansible playbook commands on Windows Remote Machine?

Tags: ansible, unzip, execution

I am unable to find an Ansible module that can unachievable or unzip a `.bz2` file in Windows Remote Machine.

The `community.windows.win_unzip` only helps in unzipping `.zip` files, but I am unable to unzip `.bz2`, `.tar`, etc. files using it. Please let me know.

Playbook **`filecontent.yaml`**

```yaml
- hosts: 192.0.2.1

  tasks:

  - name: unzip a bz2 file
    community.windows.win_unzip:
    args:
      src: C:/workdir/Samplefile.tar.bz2
      dest: C:/workdir/
      remote_src: yes
```

Inventory file **`hosts.yaml`**

```ini
cpta:
  children:
    win_vm:
      hosts: 192.0.2.1
      vars:   
        ansible_connection: winrm
        ansible_password: <omitted>
        ansible_user: Administrator
```

Command:

```bash
ansible-playbook -i hosts.yaml filecontent.yaml
```

Could anyone please help?

Tried with `community.windows.win_unzip` and `ansible.builtin.unarchive`.

- `ansible.builtin.unarchive` doesn't work for Windows Target
- `community.windows.win_unzip` doesn't support extraction of `.bz2` files

Comment: Would it be possible to have the file on a central fileshare or directly on the Linux Control Node, extract it there and transfer it from there to the Remote Node? Unfortunately there is almost no information given about the archive file, the size and content and what you finally try to achieve ...